# Manejo de campos vacíos y valores por default MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente `script`:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["apellido"]) && isset($_POST["edad"])) {
        if($_POST["nombre"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE nombre=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El nombre ya está registrado.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO registros (nombre,apellido,edad,created_at) VALUE (\"$_POST[nombre]\",\"$_POST[apellido]\",\"$_POST[edad]\",NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El script corre perfectamente. La idea es insertar en una tabla mysql un nombre, un apellido, y la edad.

Ahora, el problema que me surge es que solo exijo el nombre como dato necesario para poder ingresar todo. El apellido y la edad, no.

Lo que quisiera hacer es modificar el script para que, en lugar de generar los registros vacíos en apellido y edad cuando no se los informa, pueda ingresar algo así como "NO INFORMA", o algún array que quede mejor en la presentación de los datos.

**EDIT 1**

He intentado poner valores por default desde phpmyadmin en la tabla, pero tampoco me salen los resultados que necesito. Me siguen quedando vacíos.

Comment: Estaría mejor si a tu tabla colocas valores por default en los campos que no sean obligatorios...

Comment: Como dice el compañero de arriba, tedrías que hacer algo así como ALTER TABLE `registros` CHANGE `nombre` `nombre` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO INFORMA';
ALTER TABLE `registros` CHANGE `apellido` `apellido` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO INFORMA'; O asignarles un valor por defecto en tu php o forzar a tu usuario que agrege los datos.

Comment: Hola! gracias por las respuestas, intenté con los default, pero no tuve resultados, me quedan los registros vacíos. Luego intenté que php me inserte valores, pero tampoco sucede nada.

Comment: Ojala nadie se apellide 'NO INFORMA'... Mas alla del chiste, los campos vacios o nulos van justamente vacios o nulos porque no estan informados. Cual es el problema que tenes con eso?

Comment: =D ... La idea es que en las tablas se muestre o se guarde un **NO INFORMA** en el campo cuando esté vacío o nulo, y un **0** en el campo de la edad, cuando estén también vacíos o nulos. Para esto armé una especie de perfil del proveedor, y debajo del título apellido y edad, queda todo vacío y siento que no queda prolijo. (aclaro que además de la edad y el apellido, también hay otros datos como la dirección y demás). Por lo tanto, quisiera que cuando no se colocan los datos, se guarde con el valor **NO INFORMA** o un **0** en el caso de los números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui te estan surgiendo dos problemas:

por una parte, debes poner en la bbdd que los campos tengan valores por defecto (como ese `NO INFORMA` que propones).

por otra parte, para que se añadan esos valores por defecto, la consulta NO DEBE incluir los campos que esten nulos (para que sea el gestor de BBDD el que haga la insercion).

Por lo tanto, en tu codigo tienes que construir la sentencia SQL unicamente con los campos que no esten null.

ASUMIENDO que todos los campos que envias estan en $_POST y no hay campos a mayores (por ej, token scrf), podrias hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!=""){
    include "conexion.php";
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  // para el campo de fecha de creacion

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registros ($fields) VALUES ($values)";

    try {

        $query = $con->query($sql);
        print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "<script>alert(\"Problema al insertar en bbdd. Nombre repetido.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";
    }
}

?>
```

lo primero que hago es usar `array_filter`. De esta manera nos devuelve en $params  un array con los parametros que `NO` estan vacios.

despues, formo dos cadenas, una con las claves de los parametros (los campos) y otra con los valores, separadas por comas. (aqui estoy asumiendo que todos los campos son cadenas, como es tu caso. Si tuvieras un int, habria que cambiar esto).

Con estas dos cadenas, formamos la sql unicamente con los campos que has enviado por el post.

finalmente, todo esta añadido en un try-catch. Tratamos de insertar el registro y, si hay algun problema, capturamos la excepcion y mostramos el mensaje correspondiente. (Esto ultimo se podria mejorar, dependiendo de tu codigo, para conocer exactamente la excepcion correspondiente.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, y para otros registros que también tengo que hacer de la misma manera. Lo que hago es cambiar de los campos que tengo en el `$_POST`. Ahora, lo campos con INT igualmente me completa con los valores default que es el valor 0. De todas maneras, así sin cambios, el script funciona perfectamente, gracias!

Comment: Hola, perdón por volver, pero estoy teniendo un problema con el script. Al poner un nombre que ya se encuentra, salta el mensaje de registro exitoso, pero no guarda ningún dato. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si te ocurre eso lo más probable es que en tu BBDD el campo nombre no sea unique. Tendrás que hacer un alter table para hacer que ese campo no admita valores repetidos

Comment: Estoy usando phpMyAdmin, y al campo **nombre** lo tengo con la llave plateada (índice si no me equivoco). Tengo el **id** con la llave dorada, que sería como primaria. Tengo entendido que con eso, el campo **nombre** es UNIQUE.

Comment: ejecuta `desc registros` en tu phpmyadmin e indica el resultado, y con eso salimos de dudas. Porque temas de "el icono tal es de color cual" no podemos saber realmente que significa :)

Comment: que buena consulta esta del `desc`, no la conocía. Efectivamente, el campo **nombre** aparece con el **key** **UNI**. Así como el **id** aparece con el valor **PRI** y **auto_increment** en el campo **extra**. Es muy buena para saber bien las características de cada campo, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El `script` me quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!=""){
    include "conexion.php";
    $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE nombre=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"El nombre ya está registrado.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";
            }else {
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  // para el campo de fecha de creacion

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registros ($fields) VALUES ($values)";



        $query = $con->query($sql);
        print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../nombre.php';</script>";

}
```

}

```
?>
```

Hice una mezcla entre el `script` original y el que fue proporcionado por @Jakala.
Como no funcionaba la excepción, lo que hice fue ponerla al principio para que genere el `alert` y no cargue ningún dato de nombre repetido.